# Turnover rate Rack storage

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to analyze the utilization of my Storage, specifically I want to create as an Output the Turnover rate of my pallet Rack I have in my simulation project, any idea on how can I calculate it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what exactly you mean by turnover and utilization.

By default, you can force stats collection in the properties of a RackSystem element:
[image]

Then, call `rackSystem.statsUtilization.mean()` or similar functions on the default statistics.

Likely, this will not help 100% and you need to collect your own data. Use the RackSystem code boxes "on put" and "on remove" and store individual agent's arrival & departure times.

Then, calculate the specific stats you need from that.